# Div animated when hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

i'm trying to make a responsive website, but i'm new to html5 and css3.
The result i'm looking for you can see on this link, the effect on the pictures on the "team" part: http://evatheme.com/templates/white/index.html#team

I have already tried to use transition for the width and background, also, i'm pretty confused on how to make the other element appear and disapear when hover.

Can anyone help me? Or give some tips on what do i have to search?

This is the code i was testing:

CSS:

```
#test {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
  transition:width 2s;
  -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari */ }

#teste {
  width:px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  transition:width 2s;
  -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari */ }

.teste:hover { width:300px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
   <div id="teste" class="teste"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

first

this is illegal:
`#teste { width:px;`
the browser simply ignore that.

i would try do something like that:

```
#test {
width:300px;
height:100px;
background:blue;
 }

#teste {
width:300px;
height:100px;
background:red;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 500ms linear;
-o-transition: all 500ms linear;
transition: all 500ms linear;
}
#test:hover #teste {
opacity: 1;
}
```

[Working JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LTmr8/)

Answer (score 0):

In the site you've provided the link to.. the three social icons are in a `div` with `class="crewman_social"`:

```
<div class="crewman_item">
    ...
    <div class="crewman_social">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

...with CSS:

```
.crewman_item .crewman_social {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 30;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 text-align: center;
 transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

And on hovering over the `div` with `class="crewman_item"`, the css with regards to `bottom` & `opacity` for `div` with `class="crewman_social"` changes to:

```
bottom: 56px;
opacity: 1;
```

**P.S:** Try using `Inspect element` in `Chrome` or `Firebug` in `Firefox` to peruse through `CSS` & `JS`.

Comment: Yeah, i tried, but it was a little bit confused for me, because there were more classes, but now i got it. Thanks.

Comment: Cool :) If my answer helped, please accept it :) Or if you've an answer, please post it :)

Comment: Now i know the basic of what i want. Next step i'm trying to find a tutorial to show a div only when we scroll the page to where the div is supposed to be. I've seen this in some websites and i'm trying to do it. Do you know a good tutorial or what i need to look for to lear that?

Comment: Maybe this helps? : http://forrst.com/posts/Change_Div_Positioning_to_Fixed_at_a_Specific_Sc-w0M ... I believe this can be achieved with css positioning of the `div` and revealing div upon scrolling to a particular point in the page (You've to monitor the scroll position using jQuery).

Comment: This website here show what i want to learn: http://themeforest.net/item/haze-one-page-responsive-parallax-theme/full_screen_preview/6929703

A site where the divs are show when we scroll down the page. Do you have any guide or tutorial where i can find? Or can u post as answer on this topic any example? That will help me alot!! i wish i could give you a + rep. Thanks again.